# Problem with regional characters (polish) in php application and ms sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, unicode

I have a problem with **regional** string characters inserted to MS SQL Server database.

There is a PHP application that connects with mssql server and inserts some data. But instead of inserting characters such as: **ą, Ą, ć, Ł, ź** (and so on - btw. these are polish regional characters), when inserted into mssql table they appear as **a, A, c, L, z**.

**Here is some background:**

- I use freetds drivers for mssql connectivity
- column type is nvarchar(MAX)
- I looked at data sent "trough wire" (with WireShark) and the UTF-8 encoded data looks ok, for example Ą is sent as U+0104.
- When inserting same string into local database instance (Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition) it works fine, but on remote host (in customer location - it is Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition 64-bit) this "de-regionalization" occurs.

It seems like this remote mssql server doesn't handle this input data sent by php application right. Can anyone see/know what can be wrong here?

Comment: What's the datatype of the target database column?

Comment: EDIT: column type is nvarchar(MAX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a rookie mistake, but I found the source of this problem according to [KB #239530](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us):

> "When SQL Server converts a Unicode string without the N prefix from Unicode to the SQL Server database's code page, any characters in the Unicode string that do not exist in the SQL Server code page will be lost."

I suppose the local instance of sqlserver in some way treats all incoming string literals as Unicode strings and that remote server doesn't, thus requiring N prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround, use `htmlentities` function before insert to database and `html_entity_decode` function after retrieve data from database. You can use `ISO-8859-2` or `Windows-1250` charset.

Comment: It want help, I don't retrieve data from this table, I only write into it and the other system uses it (not for html/www presentation).